# OpenGL android 2D projection matrix

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using OpenGLES20 with android and I would like to know how to do the following:

I think it's easier to explain with a picture...

[image]

How can I rectify this stretching. Note: I am working in 2D.

I've heard this problem is solved using something called a projection matrix. I have also read a StackOverflow question saying that the android documentation for setting up a projection matrix is not good. I have tried it personally and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You actually do not even need a projection matrix to solve this. You could just multiply your vertex coordinates to adjust for aspect ratio. However, conceptually, that is one of the things that a projection matrix does. That diagram could use some work though - I am not sure if you ***want*** the image on the right or not, and if you do not want it, I do not know how much of the screen you want the triangle to take up. Maybe if you actually added some vertex coordinates I could better see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Sorry for the ambiguity, I want the image on the right to be an equilateral triangle and not get stretched like it is. Currently I am converting to screen coordinates, then performing the transformations, then converting back to openGL coordinates. But I have to use a lot of multiplication and division that is lagging my animations. So I want to know how to use a projection matrix and camera view to do this for me

Answer (score 0):

This question is extremely poorly put. On the left image you have rectangular view with coordinate system `[0,1]x[0,1]` and a correctly drawn triangle while on the right you have the same view with view coordinate system and stretched triangle... Taking this 2 things into consideration your triangle coordinates are already stretched to begin with (or there is an extra model view matrix). If they weren't stretched the triangle would be drawn correctly on the right image.

It is a very common issue your scene is stretched when dealing with different view ratios. In general to solve this you are looking for something like `glOrtho` which can define your coordinate system. The input parameters for this method are left, right, top and bottom and it is easiest to simply use screen coordinates (like presented on the right image). Another approach is to normalise this input to either `[0,1]x[0,height/width]` or `[0,width/height]x[0,1]`. These two methods represent "fit" and "fill" and which is which depends on width of view being smaller or larger then height (portrait, landscape).

When using a correct orthographical matrix your square will always be a square without using any additional matrices or multiplying the vertex arrays... In your case it seems you already multiplied your vertices so I suggest you remove that, all of it. If you can not and those vertices will continue to be scaled incorrectly I suggest you use model view matrix to rescale them.